# FBReactNativeSpec : Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code not running any ios project React native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xcode, react-native

{"name":"React-Codegen","version":"0.68.2","summary":"Temp pod for generated files for React Native","homepage":"https://facebook.com/","license":"Unlicense","authors":"Facebook","compiler_flags":"-DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -Wno-nullability-completeness","source":{"git":""},"header_mappings_dir":"./","platforms":{"ios":"11.0"},"source_files":"**/*.{h,mm,cpp}","pod_target_xcconfig":{"HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS":""$(PODS_ROOT)/boost" "$(PODS_ROOT)/RCT-Folly" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-Codegen/react/renderer/components" "$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers/Private/React-Fabric" "$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers/Private/React-RCTFabric""},"dependencies":{"FBReactNativeSpec":["0.68.2"],"React-jsiexecutor":["0.68.2"],"RCT-Folly":["2021.06.28.00-v2"],"RCTRequired":["0.68.2"],"RCTTypeSafety":["0.68.2"],"React-Core":["0.68.2"],"React-jsi":["0.68.2"],"ReactCommon/turbomodule/core":["0.68.2"]}}
which node

/usr/local/bin/node
react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
(node:54083) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
System:
OS: macOS 12.6
CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 196.59 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.14.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.11 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: Not Found
Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.10.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 19.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:

whilr running any ios project i'm getting this issue FBReactNativeSpec : Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code not running any ios project React native
i even uninstall react native and install again same with node . My node version is
v18.14.0[image]